# How to loop back in python to specific point

Tags: python, goto, continue

I have a code:

I want my program to go back to for loop after the 3rd if statement is executed. When I use "continue" it goes back to the 2nd if statement and not back to the for loop. Any idea how to accomplish this? Thanks.

```
row = 0  
for line in fh:

    if line.startswith('CREATE'):
        startrow = row
    if row > startrow:
        if line.startswith('PRIMARY KEY'): (then go to the for loop)
        print row
    row = row + 1
```

Comment: Explain what you want to do, not *how* you want to do it. So far your question does not contain your goal.

Comment: Basically I want to capture those rows that are between the lines that start with 'create ' and end with 'Primary key'. There are multiple such lines in my file. So I want my program execution to go back to the for loop once it encounters the line that start with 'Primary key'.

Comment: Use a Boolean flag to switch on and off the output of lines at key locations and let the loop run normally.

Comment: I can't see why it won't work, but that is why [goto is considered harmful](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~storm/teaching/reader/Dijkstra68.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried using a flag .. and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the description in the comment, you're looking to print ranges of lines matching certain conditions, much like `awk '/^CREATE/,/^PRIMARY KEY/ {print}'`. For some reason you've planned this with a goto, from a concept of nested loops, which are just not present. We could write nested loops, but we don't need to.

```
printing = False
for line in fh:
    if line.startswith('PRIMARY KEY'):
        printing = False
    if printing:
        print row
    if line.startswith('CREATE'):
        printing = True
```

This variant starts out not printing lines, starts printing lines after encountering CREATE, and stops again immediately upon encountering PRIMARY KEY. You can reorder the three tests to achieve other combinations like printing the lines containing those keywords.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped!

Comment: @Bhaskar Don't forget to tick the answer as accepted when it solved your question.